# How can I print selected drowndown names and testbox names based on the selection?

Tags: jquery

I have to print selected drowndown names and textbox names based on the selection.

I have a set of dropdown lists and two textboxes. While selecting values from the dropdown like test / platform and datefrom I have to print values from test,bplatform and date.

```
<div id="inputForm" style="background:#F2F9FA">
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto;float:right;">
        <b>Date &amp; Time (From - To):</b><br/><input id="datetimepickerfrom" name="date" type="text" style="width:125px;" >
        - <input name="date" id="datetimepickerto" type="text" style="width:125px;" >
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto;">
        <b>Filters:</b><br/>
        <select class="longcombo filterCombo" name ="test" id="testnames"></select>
        <select class="longcombo filterCombo" name ="user name" id="usernames" style="width:150px;"></select>
        <select class="longcombo filterCombo" name ="platform" id="platforms"></select>
        <select class="longcombo filterCombo" name ="result" id="res" style="width:105px;"></select>
      </div>&nbsp;
      <br><br>
     </div>
```

Comment: i dont know how to perform this.i just created a div elemnt to add the printed details..but dont know to get the values to print

Comment: You should start with basic tutorial like http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ . It does not help you if someone just gives you the complete solution for this and it's not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: You created a `<div>` element to hold the output? Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct you just want help with accessing the selections with jQuery?

Something like:

```
$('#inputForm')
    .on('change', '#datetimepickerto', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    }).on('change', '#testnames', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    }).on('change', '#usernames', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    }).on('change', '#platforms', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    }).on('change', '#res', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: i have to add the selected names to a div elelmt

Comment: then something like $('#divelement').append($(this).val());

Comment: I have no idea of what you want to do but maybe this is what you are looking for: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kF8as/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to get the values of input text-boxes and drop-downs.

e.g. `$("#datetimepickerfrom").val();`, `$("#testnames").val();`

And you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to set the div.

Please check the DEMO.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9U67Q/)